# Plugin github no Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, github

Fui tentar baixar o plugin Github Mylyn Connector 2.3 mas quando vai instalar, retorna o seguinte erro:

```
No repository found at http://download.eclipse.org/egit/github/updates-2.3.
```

Alguém sabe como resolvo isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse repositório foi movido para http://archive.eclipse.org/egit/github/updates-2.3/

Arrume a URL do repositório em Preferences → Install/Update → Available Software Sites.

Comment: Obrigado por responder, após fazer o que pediu, no Marketplace só aparece o link para o antigo repositório, como eu altero, você sabe?

Comment: É só selecionar, clicar em Edit e atualizar a URL.

Comment: Não vai, mesmo atualizando, quando vou pra baixar novamente, ele vai na url antiga.

Comment: Vá ao caminho Window -> Preferences -> Install/Update -> Available Software Sites, você vera a lista de URLs que vem no eclipse e que você adicionou, marque apenas a que você não quer e remova, depois  vá em Add... e adicione o URL  http://archive.eclipse.org/egit/github/updates-2.3/, já testei e esta funcionando.